# Serving binary/buffer/base64 data from Nodejs

Tags: audio, node.js, binary, base64, buffer

I'm having trouble serving binary data from node. I worked on a node module called **node-speak** which does TTS (text to Speech) and return a base64 encoded audio file.

So far I'm doing this to convert from `base64` to Buffer/binary and then serve it:

```
// var src = Base64 data
var binAudio = new Buffer(src.replace("data:audio/x-wav;",""), 'base64');
```

Now I'm trying to serve this audio from node with the headers like so:

```
res.writeHead(200, {
  'Content-Type': 'audio/x-wav',
  'Content-Length': binAudio.length
});
```

And serving it like so:

```
res.end(binAudio, "binary");
```

But its not working at all. Is there something I havnt quite understood or am I doing something wrong, because this is not serving a valid `audio/x-wav` file.

*Note*: The Base64 data is valid i can serve it like so [see below] and it works fine:

```
// assume proper headers sent and "src" = base64 data
res.end("<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><audio src=\"" + src + "\"/></body></html>");
```

So why can I not serve the binary file, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things are wrong.

1. not `Conetnt-Length`, it's `Content-Length`
2. `res.end(binAudio, "binary");` is wrong. Use `res.end(binAudio);`. With `"binary"`, it expects a string - `binary` is a deprecated string encoding in node, use no encoding if you already have a buffer.

Comment: Thanks for noticing the typo, i should have seen that when pasting the code into SO. and thanks for the answer.

I'm still having issues but at elast its serving a valid `audio/x-wav` file now.

Comment: thanks for your help, if you have a moment could you have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8354936/371040